# How to remove nested key from json object?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object with "start" and "end" keys inside in all levels.

I want to not have "start" and "end" keys and values in the object.

how to do it? I try to use `omit` form `lodash` but it remove only in the first level, so this solution not enough.

```
{
  "type": "...",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 93,
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "...",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 93,
      "more": {
        "type": "...",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 93,
```

Comment: have you tried a recursive solution?

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
  o = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(o, (key, value) => {
      if (key === "start" || key === "end") return undefined;

      return value;
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
function removeKeys(obj) {
    if (obj && Object.keys(obj).length) {
        delete obj.start;
        delete obj.end;

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                obj[key].forEach(removeKeys);
            } else if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === 'object' ) {
                removeKeys(obj[key]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Recursively deletes the start and end keys in all nested objects.